# C# lambda contents won't happen until it's called, right? Also, code cleanup

Tags: c#, refactoring, lambda, dry

I have the following methods:

```
protected static void updateExistingSection(XmlDocument doc,
    XmlNode rootNode, string sectionTag, CreateSection createSection,
    Func<XmlNode[]> createChildNodes, Action<XmlNode> firstSection)
{
    IEnumerable<XmlNode> sections =
        getChildNodesByName(rootNode, sectionTag);
    if (sections.Count() < 1)
    {
        rootNode.AppendChild(createSection(doc, createChildNodes()));
        return;
    }
    removeSubsequentNodes(sections, rootNode, firstSection);
}

private static void updateExistingCredentialsSection(XmlDocument doc,
    XmlNode rootNode, string newUser, string newPassword, string newHost)
{
    updateExistingSection(doc, rootNode, CREDENTIALS_SECTION_TAG,
        createCredentialsSection,
        () => new[] {
            createNode(USER_TAG, doc, newUser),
            createNode(PASSWORD_TAG, doc, newPassword),
            createNode(HOST_TAG, doc, newHost)
        },
        credentialsNode =>
        {
            updateExistingLeafNode(USER_TAG, doc, credentialsNode, newUser);
            updateExistingLeafNode(PASSWORD_TAG, doc, credentialsNode,
                newPassword);
            updateExistingLeafNode(HOST_TAG, doc, credentialsNode, newHost);
        });
}
```

My question concerns the fifth parameter passed in `updateExistingCredentialsSection` to `updateExistingSection`, the `() => new[] { createNode(USER_TAG, doc, newUser), ... }` one.  It was my understanding that those `createNode` calls will not occur unless that lambda expression is called in `updateExistingSection`, right?  Likewise for the `updateExistingLeafNode` calls in the last parameter given to `updateExistingSection`.

Also, from a design perspective, does either method look ridiculous?  Do you see a way I could make either method smaller, or require fewer parameters?  I've been trying to DRY things out, which is what led to writing `updateExistingSection` in the first place, since I had several methods doing the same functionality.

Comment: Readability-wise it might be better if both lambdas are declared as separate methods, especially if they are used more than once, like this you have too many });} blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct.  Think of the lambdas as methods.  You can define them anywhere (legally allowed), but the code within them is not run until explicitly invoked.

In fact, the code for some lambdas might never be be run in a given execution path if there is branching logic in the function you pass them to.